# jquery validation only digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am having the jquery.validate.js plugin and it is working fine for me.

My question is :

I am having a textbox and this textbox is mandatory and should only accept digits.

In the js, I can see that there is validation for the digits and the problem is that I do not know how to use it.

I only knew how to make the field required by putting in the textbox field `<class="required">`

So, how can I add one more validation criteria to accept only digits.

Thanx

Answer (score 79, accepted):

to check it add

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    amount: {
      required: true,
      digits: true
    }
  }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits

Comment: Thank you my fried, but if i am using the validation in the jsp like
 <input type="text" name="amount" size="10" value="<%=amount%>" id="amount" class="required" minlength="1" maxlength="10"> How do I add the digits with them

Comment: @maas put digits as a class next to required.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#mobile_number").validate({
            rules: {

                mobile_number: {required: true,number:true}
            },
            messages: {
                mobile_number: {required: "Please Enter Your Mobile Number",number:"Please enter numbers Only"}
            }

 });
```